# How does if inside for loop change big O (time complexity) of a function?

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I tried to find something similar but wasn't successful, if a question like this exists, my apologies. Back to the topic.
I've started digging in the Big O notation and stuff. However I came to a problem where I have no idea how the if statement inside this specific function affect the big O.

```
def function(n):
for i in range(n):
    if i == 0:
        for j in range(n):
            for k in range(10000):
                print("something")
```

I know the if statement will be true only once but it has to check every time.
I need to calculate big O as a polynomial (not just O(n) but something like 10n+2 etc.)
Can you help me out there? 
At first I thought it would be O(10001n) but the site with this exercise doesn't agree.

Comment: What is the purpose of `for i in range(n):` here apart from serving as a human appendix?

Comment: O(100001*n) is still O(n)

Comment: "I need to calculate big O as a polynomial (not just O(n) but something like 10n+2 etc.) " That's not how big-oh works

Comment: I know it doesn't work like that... I just need it this way right now. And there is no point to the first loop, it's just there.